# Why does this OpenMP code crash using Clang, but not GCC or ICC

Tags: c++, clang, openmp

The following code compiles and runs successfully with the Intel Compiler 19.x and with GCC 10 (`g++ -fopenmp -std=c++17`).

However, when compiled with Clang 12.x based Intel Compiler 2022, it crashes with an access violation. Is my code not OpenMP correct or is this a Clang issue or Intel fork of Clang issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>> data;


void DoTask(int a, int b)
{
    {
#pragma omp critical
        std::cout << "Thread " << omp_get_thread_num() << ' ' << a << ',' << b << std::endl;
    }
}


void test2()
{
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
#   pragma omp single
        {
            for (auto iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); ++iter)
            {
                const auto &a = iter->first;
                const auto &b = iter->second;
                for (const auto &aa : b)
                {
                    if (aa != a)
                    {
#   pragma omp task
                        DoTask(a, aa);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




int main()
{
    std::vector<int> tmp({ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        data.push_back({ i,tmp });
    }
    std::cout << "Starting test using iter " << std::endl;
    test2();

}
```

Comment: Does it crash if you remove the ampersands after `const auto` ?

Comment: Neither g++ 11.1.0 nor clang 13.0.0 complains about your code. Diagnostic utilities issue some warnings, but it is not clear whether they are real problems or just false positives.

Comment: I am *unable to reproduce this* with Clang 8.0.1-9, Clang 11.1.0-4+b2 and Clang 13.0.0-9+b2 with `-fopenmp -std=c++17`... What precise version of Clang did you use? Which one of libomp too? Are the flags the same than GCC? Can you provide the assembly code generated by Clang so to be able to track what is going on?

Comment: The code does not crash if the & is removed after const auto.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, I got no crash on Clang 12.0.1-17+b1 too. Maybe the minor version have an impact (it may have been fixed) on the problem or something else matters more than the version of the compiler (I tested on libomp 12.0.1-17+b1 which should be shared with ICC, on a 6-core machine without HT). Note that the generated assembly code for reference appear to be incorrect regarding the specification but in the end it should not cause a crash (and actually do not on my machine).